Smart Contract Execution Transaction Fee
I want to write a smart contract that receives tokens, deducts specific amount of the received tokens and then forwards the rest to a specific destination address. I have a couple of questions:
1- Does this process require one or two gas fee payments? If the answer is two, who would pay the second gas fee?
2- Can I store the deducted amount inside the contract or should I also forward these tokens to my wallet address?

It depends on the used token standard. If you use the most typical tokens, using ERC-20 standard, your idea requires two transactions. That's because the standard doesn't include any way to let the recipient know that they have received tokens. So your contract has to be told that they have received the tokens (and to do something with them) - most likely in a separate transaction.
Payer of the second transaction depends on how you design your system. But if nobody else has incentives to execute that functionality in your contract, then most likely it has to be you who executes (and pays for) it.
You can store the deducted tokens inside the contract if you want, that's not a problem. Just design all the needed functionality properly.
